# getting rid of tnsanme.ora

Tags: oracle, networking

- List item

  - What is the best way to get rid of tnsnames.ora file on each client
    pc ?
  - Can we use Oracle "transparent gateway"  - which uses ODBC drivers to
    eliminate "tnsname.ora"  file alto gather --to facilitate "oracle to
    oracle"  connections?
  - We know one can use Oracle "transparent gateway" to connect to
    heterogeneous  databases connection e.g., DB2, SQL  Server. But can
    we use it for Oracle to Oracle?
  - Any suggestions as to  how to get rid of tnsnames.ora?

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve?  You could install Oracle Internet Directory so that the TNS aliases are managed centrally rather than locally.  But that is a non-trivial amount of effort.  I suppose you could use the transparent gateway for Oracle to Oracle connections though I'm hard-pressed to imagine why you would want to.  The cure is likely worse than whatever disease you have.  An ODBC connection would generally require a TNS alias so it would generally use a local tnsnames.ora file and then you'd be managing local ODBC DSN's rather than local tnsnames.ora files.

Comment: ODBC works also when name is resolved by a name server. It does not require local resolving with local tnsnames.ora file. Actually it should work also when you put the full name into ODBC, as you can do like `sqlplus scott/tiger@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER= DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DB1)))"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that when you provide a name server which resolves the TNS alias for you.

With current Oracle you can use:

- local naming naming method (which requires an `tnsnames.ora` file)
- directory naming naming method (e.g. with an LDAP Server)
- easy connect naming method
- CDS external naming method
- Network Information Service (NIS) external naming method

Check Oracle documentation [Configuring Naming Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/naming.htm), resp. [NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/sqlnet.htm#BIIGEAHH) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your quick  response.  My problem is that we have more than 20 Oracle databases and every time when someone gets a new PC or new database is created - that TNSNAmes file needs to be updated, We still have a plenty of legacy client server (two-tier - fat client applications. Your suggestion that we can use Oracle internet directory (OID) in conjunction with Microsft LDAP. Correct? Can we use Microsoft LDAP only without OID? this way we can we get rid of client based Tnsname? correct?